# Are fonts considered software?

Tags: licensing, font

Are all fonts considered software, or does it depend on the font?

What sort of licences do and don't make sense for fonts?

Comment: I'd suggest you split the third question into it's own question, otherwise this will be too broad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does using GNU Unifont in a game make the game GPL?](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2033/does-using-gnu-unifont-in-a-game-make-the-game-gpl)